# Matrix multiplication in Feynman's paper on quantum mechanical computers

Tags: quantum-information, notation, quantum-computer

In a [paper](http://www.quantum-dynamic.eu/doc/feynman85_qmc_optics_letters.pdf) by Feynman, on how to embed a Turning machine in the ground state of a many-body quantum system, a product of two matrices is defined (equation 1). This product does not appear to have the normal row column matrix multiplication, and I was wondering what how to interpret it?
$$
\begin{align}
\underline{a}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1\\
    0       & 0
\end{bmatrix},\\
\underline{a^*}&=\begin{bmatrix}\tag{1}
    0       & 0\\
    1       & 0
\end{bmatrix},\\
\underline{a^*a^{}}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0\\
    0       & 0
\end{bmatrix},\\
\underline{a^{}a^*}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0\\
    0       & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$
Is there some inner product rule that I am unaware of, which is standard practice in this context? Or does the underlined notation refer to something?

Comment: This *is* just normal matrix multiplication. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @d_b Sorry, I wrote the matrices backwards (I wrote $a$ as $a^*$ and $a^*$ as $a$, before the edit). Thank you for pointing this mistake out.